# Syntax error with paste special

Tags: vba, excel, syntax, paste

```
Cells(R, DataCol).Resize(, ColumnCount).Copy Cells(R, DataCol) _ 
.Offset(RowOffset * (R -  StartRow), ColOffset).PasteSpecial xlValues
```

Can anyone tell me why the statement above is a syntax error, and how I can get the statement to allow me to use paste special or paste value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Copy` method only has a single (optional) argument: Destination. This is the `Range` that you are copying to.

`PasteSpecial` is a separate method. You would use `Copy` and then a separate statement to perform the PasteSpecial.

You are mixing up these two approaches. You either want to Copy immediately to a Destination, or to Copy and then PasteSpecial, requiring two separate statements. For example:

```
Cells(R, DataCol).Resize(, ColumnCount).Copy
Cells(R, DataCol).Offset(RowOffset * (R -  StartRow), ColOffset).PasteSpecial xlValues
```

Comment: Great response, that works well, & very educational. One more question thats been bugging me. Why when you copy a block of multiple cells ie.

Comment: lets say a range A1:D1, & you apply the worksheet function "change" By value, target as range - I will get a changed value four times, however when including an offset in the changed columns excel only recognizes the first column of the paste operation (A1 for this case)?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean. If I copy and paste an area it only triggers a single Change event. Perhaps you should start a new thread and provide some code.

Comment: OK will do. I actually wrote it backwards. When I use offset for a block of cells as example above, when I use the last cell in the block as a target excel doesn't recognize the change. However when I use the first block of the cells Excel gives me 4 val's of change

Comment: Change by Val, target as range not being recognized @andrew gibson

Answer (score 2):

No need to copy/paste for just values - you can assign directly:

```
With ActiveSheet.Cells(R, DataCol)
   .Offset(RowOffset * (R -  StartRow), ColOffset).Resize(,ColumnCount).Value= _
                        .Resize(, ColumnCount).Value
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

In few words, there are some syntax available but you mixed them up. So, most popular syntax to use are as follows:

```
'A)- all in one line
Range().Copy Range()   'range to copy >> destination range

'B)- instructions are in separate lines
Range().Copy           'range to copy
Range().PasteSpecial xlValues   'destination range

'C)- instructions are in separate lines
Range().Copy           'range to copy
Sheets().Paste          'destination sheet, activecell/default cell in destination sheet
```